# Compare Array of different lengths?

Tags: java

I have two String array, which have almost the same data, but I want to do is compare the values ​​one by one because they have different lengths.
This is my code, but as you see it is not efficient.

```
String arrayIdent[] = {"abanico","camboya","retrato","ovalado"};

String arrayDatos[] = {"camboya","retrato","ovalado","granizo","riachuelo"};

for(int k = 0; k < Constantes.arrayDatos.length; k++)
{
       if(arrayIdent[k].equals(arrayDatos[k]))
            System.out.println(arrayIdent[k] + " equal " + arrayDatos[k]);
       else
            System.out.println(arrayIdent[k] + " is not equal to " + arrayDatos[k]);
}
```

I can help with the problem.

Comment: Looks efficient to me.

Comment: This is `O(n)`, which isn't too bad at all.

Comment: You will get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception there. You are iterating over the index of larger array, and accessing smaller array on that index.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll get `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` if you run this code.

Comment: Arrays are unsorted so other than `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` you will never get equals succeeding.

Comment: If you're comparing the Arrays for equality and not just their elements one by one, you may want to add before the for loop something like: if(arrayIdent.length != arrayDatos.length){ System.out.println("Arrays are not equal"); return;}

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking for here. What sort of output do you expect from the comparison? (Also ditto on `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` thing people already mentioned)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to compare element by element on k-th position or one element against other elements? If one against other then the source code:

```
String arrayIdent[] = { "abanico", "camboya", "retrato", "ovalado" };
String arrayDatos[] = { "camboya", "retrato", "ovalado", "granizo", "riachuelo" };

boolean found;    
for (int k = 0; k < arrayIdent.length; k++)
{
   found = false;
   for (int j = 0; j < arrayDatos.length; j++)
      if(arrayIdent[k].equals(arrayDatos[j]))
      {
         System.out.println(arrayIdent[k] + " is equal to " + arrayDatos[j]);
         found = true;
      }
   if (!found)
      System.out.println(arrayIdent[k] + " is not equal to any element");
}
```

If you want to compare whole arrays then [equal()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) method works with different length also.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the two lists I'm guessing you expect "camboya", "retrato", and "ovalado" to show up as equal at some point, since you say search one-by-one.

If that is the case you'll need to use a second for-loop nested in the first one to compare all the elements against eachother.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayDatos.length; i++){
    for (int k = 0; k < arrayIdent.length; k++){
        if(arrayIdent[k].equals(arrayDatos[i]))
            System.out.println(arrayIdent[k] + " equal " + arrayDatos[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As someone mentioned, `arrayDatos` is longer than `arrayIndent`. This will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception. Your method is perfectly efficient, but you may want to instead write your loop as:

```
for (int k=0; k<Math.min(Constantes.arrayDatos.length, Constantes.arrayIndent.length); k++)
```